# Deriving bip84 addresses with python

Tags: private-key, script, public-key, python, bip-84

Does anyone have a python script deriving the bip84 addresses from the private key?

I do have the private root key so I don't need to go all the way from the private key.

I'd like to do this with the minimum amount of libraries.

Thank you so much in advance!

Best,
Peder

Answer (score 0):

```
from hdwallet import BIP84HDWallet
from hdwallet.cryptocurrencies import BitcoinMainnet

wallet = BIP84HDWallet(cryptocurrency=BitcoinMainnet)

wallet.from_private_key(private_key="YOUR_PRIVATE_KEY")
address = wallet.address()
```